# Angular form same line fields

Tags: angular, forms

I have this format in a project in angular and I want to put the red fields in the same row. I would like to do the same for the greens.

[image]

The code is this. how can I do it;

```
<!-- BUY PRICE -->
  <div class="form-group">
  <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
    <mat-label>Buy price</mat-label>
    <input matInput formControlName="buy_price" placeholder="Enter buy price">
    <span matPrefix>€&nbsp;</span>
  </mat-form-field>
  </div>

  <!-- FIRST BID -->
  <div class="form-group">
    <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
      <mat-label>First Bid Price</mat-label>
      <input matInput formControlName="first_bid" placeholder="Enter 1st bid price">
      <span matPrefix>€&nbsp;</span>
    </mat-form-field>
  </div>

<!--LOCATION-->
<div class="form-group">
  <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
    <mat-label>Location(City,Region)</mat-label>
    <input matInput formControlName="location" placeholder="Enter location">
  </mat-form-field>
</div>

<!-- COUNTRY -->
<div class="form-group">
  <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
    <mat-label>Country</mat-label>
    <mat-select  formControlName="country">
      <ng-container *ngFor="let country of countries">
        <mat-option  [value]="country.name">{{country.name}}</mat-option>
      </ng-container>
    </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wrap the two form-group divs that you want on the same line in a wrapping div and apply **display: flex** to it and then **flex-grow: 1** and **flex-basis:50%** to each of the form-group divs - you will get them onto the same line.

Note that the following is the code from your post - and so does not work because I don't have the required md code etc, - but the relevent divs are aligned horizontally on the same row and I have put a border around them so you can see the effect of the flex styling.

```css
.form-group-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  margin-bottom:16px;
}

.form-group-wrapper .form-group{
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-basis: 50%;
  padding: 8px;
  border: solid 1px red;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group-wrapper">
  <!-- BUY PRICE -->
  <div class="form-group">
  <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
    <mat-label>Buy price</mat-label>
    <input matInput formControlName="buy_price" placeholder="Enter buy price">
    <span matPrefix>€&nbsp;</span>
  </mat-form-field>
  </div>

  <!-- FIRST BID -->
  <div class="form-group">
    <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
      <mat-label>First Bid Price</mat-label>
      <input matInput formControlName="first_bid" placeholder="Enter 1st bid price">
      <span matPrefix>€&nbsp;</span>
    </mat-form-field>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group-wrapper">
  <!--LOCATION-->
  <div class="form-group">
    <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
      <mat-label>Location(City,Region)</mat-label>
      <input matInput formControlName="location" placeholder="Enter location">
    </mat-form-field>
  </div>

  <!-- COUNTRY -->
  <div class="form-group">
    <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
      <mat-label>Country</mat-label>
      <mat-select  formControlName="country">
        <ng-container *ngFor="let country of countries">
          <mat-option  [value]="country.name">{{country.name}}</mat-option>
        </ng-container>
      </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
  </div>
</div>
```